# How to introduce a static method of a class to a namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, using-directives

For example, I have a class `A` and a static method `foo` for the class. I have a namespace `nm` and want to introduce A::foo to the namespace. I try the following

```
namespace nm {
    using A::foo;

    void f()
    {
        foo(...); // use A::foo
    }
}
```

But cannot compile because A is not a namespace, thus using directive does not work here. Any way to implement this idea? I want to use it for QObject::tr and QObject::connect in my GUI project to save some space.

Comment: If I am not wrong, a static method is a class method, and why should it be possible to make it a namespace function? Why simply not using the method directly Class.method() in whatever thing you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. [namespace.udecl]/8:

> A *using-declaration* for a class member shall be a *member-declaration*. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   int i;
>   static int s;
> }
>
> void f() {
>   using X::i; // error: X::i is a class member
>               // and this is not a member declaration.
>   using X::s; // error: X::s is a class member
>               // and this is not a member declaration.
> }
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]

But you can simulate `foo` using SFINAE and perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args)
  -> decltype(A::foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return    A::foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Hm. Maybe we should have a `using static` to introduce all `static` symbols of that name for class-members.

Comment: @Deduplicator That would *never* get accepted by the committee.